# How to wrap left navigation block at magento

Tags: magento

I encountered so much difficult to wrap my left navigation block into my own DIV container

At layout/customer.xml

### It looks like

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <remove name="tags_popular"/>
        </reference>
```

---

So left block is being assembled from next templates

```
customer/account/navigation.phtml
checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml
catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml
```

How can I wrap them to my wrapper like

```
  <div class="mywrapper">
// ... all content from templates
  </div>
```

????

I dont want to add open wrapper to the first template and add close wrapper to last one

could I add it in layout/customer.xml ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would add in it in the respective page template, not via XML - as you point out you would never get that right and would be forced to have the block containing your opening tag first and the one with the closing tag last.

So if open up `template/page/2columns-left.phtml` (or `3columns.phtml` which will also have a left sidebar) then add our markup there instead;

```
    <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-left sidebar">
               <div class"yourDivHere">
                  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First of all 
Thanks to McNab

Really your advice is very correct but at my situation
Unfortunately This ways isnt good for me because There is next order of template execution 
        <?=$this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')?>
        <?=$this->getChildHtml('left')?>
        <?=$this->getChildHtml('content')?>
in my 3columns.phtml

There are a lot of page which works with 3columns.phtml and if I will wrap it here they will become broken 

I need to modify layout/customer.xml only

Comment: I found decision I added
<block type="core/template" name="customer.account.wrapNavBegin" before="-" template="customer/account/wrapperNavBegin.phtml"/>

Before I added also but I didnt use " type="core/template" "
I have other type )

Comment: Glad you sorted it, good on you for feeding back and updating :)